# Paging issue when data source is changed by ajax - Infragistics WebDataGrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, infragistics

I have changed data-source of `Infragistics` `WebDataGrid` using ajax as below.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "TestCS.aspx/GetDocumentsAjax",
    data: '{}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var grdDoc = $find("DocumentListGrid");
        grdDoc.set_dataSource(response);
        grdDoc._pi.show(grdDoc);
        grdDoc.applyClientBinding();
        grdDoc._pi.hide(grdDoc);
    }
});
```

And it has worked but the data is not divided into pages and I am getting all data at once. Is there any client side thing that could help me persisting paging, sorting info?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you do not have the old data source specified for the paging. See [this link](http://www.infragistics.com/samples/aspnet/data-grid/paging-previous-next-pager).

Comment: I have new datasource set.

Comment: There is no paging code. Just set enable paging and pagesize